# update datagridview after new row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and a custom list. I bind it using:

```
datagridview.DataSource = MyList;
```

The problem is whenever I add new rows to the list from a thread, it doesn't show the new rows in DataGridView. Is there a way I can simply overwrite `OnNewData` type of event `DoRefresh()` and possibly without losing scroll position?

SyncList I'm using:

```
   public class SyncList<T> : System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke _SyncObject;
        private System.Action<System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs> _FireEventAction;

        public SyncList()
            : this(null)
        {
        }

        public SyncList(System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke syncObject)
        {

            _SyncObject = syncObject;
            _FireEventAction = FireEvent;
        }

        protected override void OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (_SyncObject == null)
            {
                FireEvent(args);
            }
            else
            {
                _SyncObject.Invoke(_FireEventAction, new object[] { args });
            }
        }
```

Comment: As far as I know, your control will not updated just because you updated `MyList`. If you are using WinForms, [a custom object list view](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) might help.

Comment: I'm using SyncList so the data is being updated 'live'. but I have to reassign the list for datagridview to show new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your list needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for automatic updates to bound controls to work. If you do this, you then need to raise the PropertyChanged event when adding or removing  items from the list.

Alternatively, just use a BindingList or ObservableCollection which already implements this interface correctly.

Binding List: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx

Observable Collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: Thanks! can you please check my updated answer and tell me if I can simply extend SyncList to make datagridview show new rows? thanks

Comment: It looks like you are overriding OnListChanged, which is why the DataGrid isn't getting the change notification events. You need to call the base classes OnListChanged:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132698.aspx